# LinQ Statement for filterings

Tags: c#

Im trying to filter out an `ObservableCollection<MainBusinessObject>` where I need to filter all items in the collection that have `Subobject.PropertyX == true`.

```
  MainBusinessObject 
     - PropertyA int
     - PropertyB string
     - ListOfSubobject ObservableCollection<Subobject>

  Subobject
     - PropertyX bool
     - PropertyY int
     - PropertyZ - string
```

I really want to stay away from looping and if statements, but I can't seem to get the LinQ statements right. This is what I have so far:

```
return (MainBusinessObjectCollection) 
          listOfMainBusinessObject.Where(x =>
           (x as MainBusinessObject).CanBePartitioned == true);
```

**EDIT**
I need to filter out the `ListOfSubobject` from the main business object

Comment: Do you mean if _any_ of the items in `ListOfSubobject` have `PropertyX == true` to ignore that MainBusinessObject altogether?

Comment: The return type of Where() is IEnumerable<T>. You can´t simply typecast it to MainBusinessObjectCollection.

Comment: @Ondra this is the issue I am dealing with currently. Is there another way around this?

Comment: @Nerd you can use ToList() method that will create List<MainBusinessObject> or create a contructor for MainBusinessObjectCollection that take IEnumerable<...> as a parameter. But as the name suggests you are using old .NET 1 approach to collections. I would probably try to change it to generics.

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending if you want ANY sub-object to have that property or ALL sub-object to have that property:

```
var filteredList = listOfMainBusinessObject
                       .Where(x => x.ListOfSubobject.Any(s=>s.PropertyX));
```

or

```
var filteredList = listOfMainBusinessObject
                      .Where(x => x.ListOfSubobject.All(s=>s.PropertyX));
```

Also you have some casts that seem to be either invalid or unnecessary.  To convert to a `MainBusinessObjectCollection` (assuming it is a collection of `MainBusinessObject`s), you're likely going to have to initialize it from the `IEnumerable` that `Where` returns:

```
var newList = new MainBusinessObjectCollection(filteredList);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all `Subobjects` with `Subobject.PropertyX == true`:

```
listOfMainBusinessObject.SelectMany(x => x.ListOfSubobject)
                        .Where(x => x.PropertyX == true);
```